# ckeditor - file renaming issue

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor

Need your kind assistance in fixing the file rename issue. I am using ckeditor to manage the content. When i upload an image say `'blue-kpi.png'` and again if i try to upload the same image it renamed the file to `'blue-kpi(1).png'`.

[image]

This works fine. I want no alert message should be displayed it directly upload the file without any alerts and file renaming functionalities will work as it is.

In short, user will not see the name of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this address and edit it functions
ckeditor\plugins\filemanager\connectors\php\io.php

// Do a cleanup of the file name to avoid possible problems
function SanitizeFileName($sNewFileName).............